# Fixed button for Telegram bot that accepts a callback

Tags: python, telegram

I have a question so in telegram bot there is a `InlineKeyboardMarkup` that can have a callback, but its not persistent, does not stick to the botton of the screen, when you write a new message it will go up, like a normal message. And on the other hand there is `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` that does persist and stay at the botton, but does not have a callback. So is there a way to create a button that stays at the botton but allso accepts a callback that you can catch with `callback_query_handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to create a button that you can capture with `callback_query_handler` in a `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`.

When you press a `KeyboardButton`, it sends a message with its text. What you could do is put your bot's commands in the buttons or you can make a message handler that captures non-command messages and execute some code for each text of your buttons.

Comment: Found a way around thnx!